# Nodemon, in express.js, executes a file other than what is specified in package.json, I

Tags: node.js, express

Starting up a node.js express app with **nodemon**. If I run my app with

```
nodemon
```

with no file specified, it starts index.js. Which fires up my express app, no problems. However, I am confused as to how it determined index.js was the correct file to start up. I looked in the package.json, for the 'main' and 'scripts' it specifies server.js, like below. Is index.js a fallback file to run for nodemon?

```
"description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If no configuration is given nodemon looks for `index.js`.

```
nodemon can be run in a number of ways:

`nodemon` - tries to use package.json#main property to run
`nodemon` - if no package, looks for index.js
`nodemon app.js` - runs app.js
`nodemon --arg app.js --apparg` - eats arg1, and runs app.js with apparg
`nodemon --apparg` - as above, but passes apparg to package.json#main (or
  index.js)
`nodemon --debug app.js
```

https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/lib/cli/parse.js#L9

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. There is a package though. So, it must try to find the file in the package, if it can't find it(or run it), then it calls index.js.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the nodemon in the scripts

```js
"description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js", //Add this
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

And to run it just type

```js
npm server
```